# pull using git got error 128

Tags: git, github

I need help I got this error when I try to pull.

[image]

Not sure what's happening and how to solve it.

Comment: Please post the entire output of `git status`

Comment: Did you do any research before asking here? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have modified the file `locales/en.json`, which is tracked by git. You need to stash the changes in order to bring in changes from the server. Try the following:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Comment: You're bringing the stashed files back into your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You have local changes in your repository and by pulling, these would be overwritten.

Easy, peasy:

`git add /your/files` (or `git add -A`)

`git commit -m "Your commit message"`

Now you can run `git pull` as your local workspace is clean :)

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: modified:   locales/en.json

Comment: This means that your working directory is not clean and requires you to run `git add locales/en.json` followed by `git commit -m "Your message"` and `git pull` afterwards.

Could it be that you committed, but forgot to add the files first?

Comment: I'm using gui. i dont' have to use -add

Comment: Well, there has to be some kind of functionality to `add` your changed files, otherwise a `commit` won't do anything thus your `pull` fails.
I suggest opening up a terminal and doing as I wrote in my answer if that's a possibility for you.